# How to fix 'File not found' error in debugging with VScode debugger gcc

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

While I was debugging a c code, my Vscode debugger for gcc showed a error like this:
'Unable to open 'test.c': Unable to read file(Error:File not found(C:\mycode\C:\mycode\test.c))'.
So why my file path exists a repetition? And how to fix it?

I had only installed these plugins:
C/C++
C++ Intellisense

Comment: Hard to tell without important information. Have a look at your configuration files.

Comment: Hi did you ever find a solution to this. Ive been trying for a few hours and got nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Change your `tasks.json` from `"args":[ "${file} ]` to `${relativeFile}`,and delete  `"cwd"` or change it to `${workspaceFolder}`.